# How can I reach this node with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Here's the start of my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}\no\\:*  {behavior:url(#default#VML);}\nw\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}\n.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}\n</style><![endif]--><style><!--\n/* Font Definitions */\n@font-face\n\t{font-family:"Cambria Math";\n\tpanose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}\n@font-face\n\t{font-family:Calibri;\n\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}\n@font-face\n\t{font-family:Tahoma;\n\tpanose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}\n/* Style Definitions */\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\n\t{margin:0in;\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\n\tfont-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}\na:link, span.MsoHyperlink\n\t{mso-style-priority:99;\n\tcolor:blue;\n\ttext-decoration:underline;}\na:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed\n\t{mso-style-priority:99;\n\tcolor:purple;\n\ttext-decoration:underline;}\np\n\t{mso-style-priority:99;\n\tmso-margin-top-alt:auto;\n\tmargin-right:0in;\n\tmso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;\n\tmargin-left:0in;\n\tfont-size:12.0pt;\n\tfont-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}\nspan.EmailStyle18\n\t{mso-style-type:personal-reply;\n\tfont-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";\n\tcolor:#1F497D;}\n.MsoChpDefault\n\t{mso-style-type:export-only;\n\tfont-size:10.0pt;}\n@page WordSection1\n\t{size:8.5in 11.0in;\n\tmargin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}\ndiv.WordSection1\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\n--> </style>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\n<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />\n</xml><![endif]--> <!--[if gte mso 9]>    <xml>\n<o:shapelayoutv:ext="edit">\n<o:idmapv:ext="edit"data="1"/>\n</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->

</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><p>&nbsp;</p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><a name="_MailEndCompose"><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><p>&nbsp;</p></span></a></p>
<div><div style="border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in"><p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> EMAIL SENDER NAME [mailto:EMAILADDRESS@FAKE.COM] <br><b>Sent:</b>!! DATE I NEED TO GRAB HERE !! <br><b>To:</b> EMAIL ADDRESS HERE <br><b>Subject:</b> SUBJECT LINE HERE <p></p></span></p></div></div>
```

I need to grab the date the email was sent. Here's what I've tried:

```
label_tag_name = 'div div p span br b'
if label_tag = @doc.at_css(%Q{#{label_tag_name}:contains("#{label}:")})
  @attributes[field] = label_tag.text.gsub("#{label}:",'').gsub("\\n", "").strip
end
```

I also tried some shorter paths in the `label_tag_name`, basically adding another HTML tag to the beginning.

Every time though, the sent date is coming back `nil`.

Comment: When you add sample data, please strip it to the bare amount necessary to act as an example. Anything more and you waste the time of those answering as they wade though the unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit of your source you're interested in is (I've removed attributes for clarity):

```
<div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <b>
        <span>From:</span>
      </b>
      <span> EMAIL SENDER NAME [mailto:EMAILADDRESS@FAKE.COM] <br>
        <b>Sent:</b>!! DATE I NEED TO GRAB HERE !! <br>
        <b>To:</b> EMAIL ADDRESS HERE <br>
        <b>Subject:</b> SUBJECT LINE HERE <p></p>
      </span></p></div></div>
```

Note that `br` tags in HTML are self closing, so it's pointless looking for child elements of them.

The target could be described with the css `div div p span`, but note that there are two nodes that match that, and `at_css` returns the *first*. You could use `div div p>span` to specify only `span`s that are immediate children on the `p`. The actual target is a text node inside this element (there's only one matching span in the document now). In particular, it's the next element after the first `b` tag. So if we expand the css selector to `div div p>span b`, we can use the Nokogiri `next` method to get the target string:

```
date_string = @doc.at_css('div div p>span b').next
```

If you want the other fields, you could use `css` instead of `at_css`:

```
date_string = @doc.css('div div p>span b')[0].next
to_string = @doc.css('div div p>span b')[1].next
subject_string = @doc.css('div div p>span b')[2].next
```

I'll leave getting the sender name for something for you to do!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to navigate on in that document. Use a selector that gets you to the closest point reliably then grab the text with a regex:

```
> doc.css("div.WordSection1 p.MsoNormal span").text[/Sent:\n(.*)/, 1]
=> "          !! DATE I NEED TO GRAB HERE !! To:"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="WordSection1">

        <div>
            <div>
                <b>Sent:</b>!! DATE I NEED TO GRAB HERE !!<br>
                <b>To:</b> EMAIL ADDRESS HERE<br>
                <b>Subject:</b> SUBJECT LINE HERE</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
EOT

text = doc.at('div.WordSection1').text
sent_date = text[/Sent:(.+)To:/, 1].strip
puts sent_date
```

Which outputs this:

```
!! DATE I NEED TO GRAB HERE !!
```

The sample HTML is a mess so you can't easily see the particular trees you want in that forest. Strip out everything that isn't essential for navigation, then build your search.

And, while a parser is a great tool, sometimes it's easier to use it to get to the text you want, then grab the particular thing via a string search.